# Unique and Range value symbology in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, symbology, feature-service

I am using ArcMap 10.1.

I am facing a issue in which I have to give symbology depending on unique value of one attribute  and range value of another attribute.
That is symbology on gender and age like:

1. symbol1 - Male(gender) and 21-30(age)
2. symbol2 - Male(gender) and 30-50(age)
3. symbol3 - Male(gender) and 50 -100(age)
4. symbol4 - Female(gender) and 21-30(age)
5. symbol5 - Female(gender) and 30-50(age)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are the only 5 categories, I suggest adding a field to the attribute table and using the field calculator to return values of 1-5 based on those conditions (e.g. *if gender="male" AND age>21 AND age<=30 then return 1*, etc.). You could then symbolize based on unique values in the calculated field.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to draw features to show quantity by category.

For that, the Online Help on [Drawing features to show quantity by category](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000035000000) will be useful to review.